# Active admin addons :search_select_filter causes uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

Active admin addons select2 search plugin docs:
https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/select2_search.md

I've got:

app/admin/users.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  filter :email, as: :search_select_filter
end
```

This results in the same error:

```
filter :email, as: :search_select_filter, fields: [:email], url: proc { admin_users_path }
```

Seems like its getting `:Email` instead of `:email` somehow ?

[image]

Maybe this closed ticket?:
https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/issues/220

Or I'm just doing something dumb and haven't realized what it is yet...

Answer (score 0):

Just do this instead:

```
filter :email_cont, as: :string, label: "Email"
```